# Translating lambda to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

1- `<IEnumerable<int>> exceptionFunction = () => list1.Except(list2);`

2-

```
Action displayList = () => exceptionFunction()
                           .ToList()
                           .ForEach(i => Debug.WriteLine(i));
```

In the code above I am able to translate line 1 to VB with no problem.

Everything I try to convert line 2. gives me an error that no value is returned.

Is this a VB limitation with Lambdas?

Answer (score 1):

It's a restriction of VB9 lambda expressions, yes. VB10 lambda expressions will be on a par with C#'s, I believe - see the [MSDN VB10 "new features" page for lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253(VS.100).aspx) for more details.